# .htaccess multi RewriteRule and RewriteCond help me to combine them together

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with the following .htaccess, i need to combine them together if its possible

This will redirect to the domainname.com.au with `http://www` at the front of domain name if there is no `http://` or `www` at the front:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.com.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname.com.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domainname.com.au\/$1" [R=301, OR]
```

And this one should get the variables that passing at the end of the domain name after slash /, I should see "/contact" but the php MVC see this "/index.php?url=contact"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

deny from 111.93.163.217
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two rules can't be combined as they're quite different, but they can be shortened:

```
# Force www
RewriteCOnd %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [B,NE,QSA,L]
```